# session username match to

Tags: php

So when a logged on user posts a comment on my webpage, it automatically posts their username next to their comment. using `<? echo $rows['a_name']; ?>`

I now want to create an edit link that will only appear on the posts that the logged in user has created.  In other words I want to match the `<? echo $rows['a_name']; ?>` to the `$_SESSION=['username']` username and if they match - display the edit link -... if not, then hide the edit link.

Any help, examples, ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [check username against forum post name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838980/check-username-against-forum-post-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if($rows['a_name']===$_SESSION['username']) { ?>
    <!-- edit link here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: OK, so the edit button is now working and only displays on posts that the logged in user has written themselevs. Do you have any ideas how I might get the value of the post that has been written to be displayed in a textbox on the edit page?

Comment: @Novice: From your other questions, it looks like you're trying to create a forum with little to no other PHP knowledge. I'd suggest you read more about PHP before taking on such a large project.